# Object is possibly undefined is not accepted with question mark

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider the following ocde:

**app-config.json**

```
{
  "auth": {
    "clientId": "acb610688b49",
  },
  "cache": {
    "cacheLocation": "localStorage"
  },
  "scopes": {
    "loginRequest": ["openid", "profile", "user.read"]
  },
  "resources": {
    "gatewayApi": {
      "resourceUri": "https://localhost:44351/api",
      "resourceScope": ["api://0e01a2d8/access_as_user"]
    }
  }
}
```

**authService.js**

```js
import { isInternetExplorer } from 'src/services/utils/utilsService'
import * as Msal from 'msal'
import * as configJson from 'src/app-config.json'

type resourceType = {
  resourceUri: string
  resourceScope: string | string[]
}

type resourcesType = {
  [key: string]: resourceType
}

interface JsonConfigInterface extends Msal.Configuration {
  scopes: {
    loginRequest: string[]
  }
  resources: resourcesType
}

const config: JsonConfigInterface = configJson as JsonConfigInterface

function MSALConfigFactory(): Msal.Configuration {
  return {
    auth: {
      clientId: config.auth.clientId,
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation?: config.cache.cacheLocation as Msal.CacheLocation,
    },
  }
}
```

The reported error for `cacheLocation?: config.cache.cacheLocation as Msal.CacheLocation` is:

> (property) cache?: CacheOptions | undefined Object is possibly
>   'undefined'.ts(2532)

When looking at the [msal documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-core/src/Configuration.ts#L107) it says:

```js
export type CacheLocation = "localStorage" | "sessionStorage";

export type CacheOptions = {
    cacheLocation?: CacheLocation;
    storeAuthStateInCookie?: boolean;
};
```

The question mark in `cacheLocation?` indicates that this parameter is optional, which is fine. It can or cannot be defined within the JSON file. So I do not understand why TypeScript complains that it can be `undefined` when that is an accepted value? Of course, the TS null check is in place, but should it not allow this as there is a question mark?

The current workaround for now is below, but I don't know if that is the correct approach:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion
cacheLocation: config.cache!.cacheLocation as Msal.CacheLocation,
```

I'm still a beginner, so thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is trying to tell you that this property access might result in an error:

```
config.cache.cacheLocation
```

If either `config` or `config.cache` turn out undefined, an exception will be raised.

You can do this:

```
config?.cache?.cacheLocation
```

It seems this is the type:

```
export type Configuration = {
    auth?: BrowserAuthOptions,
    cache?: CacheOptions,
    system?: BrowserSystemOptions
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems logical. Can you elaborate on why there's no error generated for `clientId: config.auth.clientId,`? In this case `config` can also be non existing right?

Comment: I don't know, I would need to see Msal.Configuration interface.

Comment: But since the other one is not erroring, that means `config` can not be undefined, only `cache`, so this would be enough: `config.cache?.cacheLocation`